# Maximize IE 9 window using webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have to maximize IE 9 window using the webdriver.

So far I have tried `driver.manage().window().maximize();` but it is showing error message:

> The method window() is undefined for the type WebDriver.Options

How to define the method `window()`?

Is there any other way that will work in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The one worked me:

```
WebDriver wbdv = new InternetExplorerDriver();
EventFiringWebDriver driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(wbdv);
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

See if this works!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i will try this code and let you know the result in couple of days.

Comment: Showing error message "The method window() is undefined for the type Webdriver.Option" The samw error message that is given priviously. can you suggest how to define the method window(). Thanks

Comment: Can you check Selenium-webdriver and IEDriverServer version?